# Get value from textarea. Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

When I try to take a value from a textfield, it works when I use this:

```
var name = $("input[name='Event[name]']").serializeArray(); 
name = name[0].value;
```

I can't get value from a **textarea**:

```
var desc = $("input[name='Event[desc]']").serializeArray();
```

Here is a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/32Dgn/1/)  to working variant with a textfield. I tried with a textarea and I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: It seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/32Dgn/3/

Comment: what textarea markup are you using? The value goes within the open and closing tags not as an attribute.

Comment: JSFiddles are useful live demos, but not a reason to not put the code *in the question*. Showing us related code that works is useful, but we can't tell what is wrong with code that you *don't* show us.

Answer (score 1):

Here buddy: http://jsfiddle.net/jVUsZ/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var val = $.trim($("textarea").val());
    if (val != "") {
        alert(val);
    }
});
```

Comment: why put minus to my question . It's stupid question?(((

Comment: To encourage you to look for existing solutions on SO

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var val = $.trim($("textarea").val());
 if (val.length !== 0) {
    alert(val);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell given that you have shown us only part of your code but:

```
var desc = $("input[name='Event[desc]']").serializeArray();
```

Your selector here only matches `<input>` elements. If you want to match a `<textarea>` element, then you have to replace `input` with `textarea` in your selector.

```
var desc = $("textarea[name='Event[desc]']").serializeArray();
```